# How can get the list test more than 250 from a run using Test Rail API

Tags: testrail

Returns a list of tests for a test run

https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/reference/tests#gettests

There is an API from Test Rail, it will return a list test case from one test run (id)

This is a limitation, only return up to 250 entities in once.

How can I get more than 400 or 500 case from a run?

Comment: Have you tried to set `limit` parameter to 400 or 500?

Comment: @Sergi it not working .... i tried it before

Answer (score 3):

Maximum and default value of `limit` parameter is 250, you can't get more than 250 with one request. But they have `offset` parameter for that, so you can set the start position of the next chunk.

And also you can use "next link" from the response, here is the example:

```
"_links": { "next": "/api/v2/get_tests/1&limit=250&offset=250", "prev": null }
```

Comment: great ..it work

Answer (score 0):

Here is some python code I wrote that will query to get all of the results.

```
def _execute_get_until_finished(self, resp, extract):
    results = []
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        results.extend(resp[extract])
        finished = resp["_links"]["next"] is None

        if not finished:
            resp = self.send_get(resp["_links"]["next"].replace("/api/v2/", "").replace("&limit=250", ""))
    return results
```

Example:

```
cases = self._execute_get_until_finished(
        self.send_get(f"get_cases/{self.project_id}/{self.suite_id}"),
        "cases")
```

Note, reason for removing limit is a bug I found where next would be null even though there were still results to retrieve.  Removing this limit fixed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for those who uses `TestRailAPI` Python libraby

I have a method like that that gets the initial call to `api.tests.get_tests()` and checks if the response's `['_links']['next']` is not `None` and keeps calling the same endpoint with a new `offset` value every call until the `['_links']['next']` is `None`

```
 def get_tests_from_test_run(self, test_run_id: int):
    """
    Returns a list of tests for a test run.
    :param test_run_id: The ID of the test run
    :return: Returns a list of test
    """

    try:
        tests = []
        data = self.api.tests.get_tests(test_run_id)
        tests.extend(data["tests"])
        while data["_links"]["next"] is not None:
            offset = int(data["_links"]["next"].split("offset=")[1])
            data = self.api.tests.get_tests(test_run_id, offset=offset)
            tests.extend(data["tests"])

        return tests

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Calling testrailApi.tests.get_tests({test_run_id}) failed")
        raise e
```